# Prevent abuse of promotion by preventing registration on same device from user

Tags: ios, udid, idfa

I am developing an app that offers discounts on newly registered users.
I want to avoid users from abusing this by preventing users from registering a different account on their device. The API I use is already checking if email and contact number (where verification code is sent) already exists and prevents the registration. I also use the device UUID and store it in the server to check if someone has registered from this device.

I have done some research for iOS and this is what I came up with:

- DeviceCheck API can be used on iOS 11+.
- UDID is deprecated.
- IDFA can be reset by the user.
- UUID can be changed once app is uninstalled or user has reset his/her device.

What would be the best way to avoid a user from abusing this business logic?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you get the solution for this ? Does storing the value in the keychain works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue 2 years ago, I have resolved the issue by storing a value in the keychain.

I have used below library to store the value in the keychain.

Reference: [Keychain wrapper class](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper)

Sample code to store uuid to device:

```
let deviceId = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString ?? ""
// Saving Id in keyChain
KeychainWrapper.defaultKeychainWrapper().setString(deviceId, forKey: "CurrentDeviceId")
```

Read data from keychain.

```
let previousDeviceId = KeychainWrapper.defaultKeychainWrapper().stringForKey("CurrentDeviceId")
```

if `previousDeviceId` value is `nil or blank` then, App install in device first time else your app installed into to device more than one time.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I've read that all versions of iOS prior to 10.3 beta preserve keychain items when an app is deleted. So 10.3 and up will not preserve keychain items anymore on uninstall.

Comment: Yes I just read that the behavior I mentioned about was not the case on final build of iOS 10.3 and up. However, can you confirm that keychain items will remain if user resets device content from settings?

Comment: Before 2 year latest iOS OS is 10.0, At that time it will work fine for me. I have checked for iOS 10.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use identifierForVendor and store in your server. So that you can check with it and prevent multiple registrations in one device.

Comment: That is what we are already doing however identifierForVendor can be changed on device reset.